# Can't log in to Debian with the correct password

Tags: linux, debian, login

I tried to log in to my machine as regular user with my password. After several attempts, I tried to log in as root with the root password. Tried using both GUI shell and tty. Everything fails.

I looked this up and found that people had these problems because of full disk space for root partition. I know that my root (I have separate root and home partitions) was full because during my last session, NetBeans complained. I also tried `rm -rf *` in /tmp thinking it had a lot of junk which may be another reason. However, I can't log in as anything now. So, I have no way to try any solution offered.

If nothing else works, I may try using a live disk to change partition size. Don't know if that will allow me to log in. However, is there any better solution?

Comment: When greeted by GRUB at boot, activate its edit more and add `init=/bin/bash` to the kernel's command line, then boot—instead of whatever `init` superserver is configured in the system, plain `bash` shell will be started—without any asking for password. You may then work from there to check what's with your disk space and/or may be change passwords (`passwd`) etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a live disk to boot and mount your current root filesystem, and then ***carefully*** delete some files in the mounted filesystem.

If /dev/sda1 is your root filesystem, the commands would be

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
cd /mnt
```